# import/export 3MF file by using script

Tags: scripting, add-on, file-format

I install [3mf add-on](https://github.com/Ghostkeeper/Blender3mfFormat), and I use Python scripting as the following but it does not work.

How can I write the script?

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.import_mesh.threemf(filepath=c:\\work\\sample.3mf)
```

Comment: Try `filepath="c:\\work\\sample.3mf"`

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I did the upper comment and it shows the following error.

`AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.import_mesh.threemf" error, could not be found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add-on somehow uses an operator name that starts with a number. That's the problem. You should report this to the author of the add-on as a bug. You can fix this by changing the text:

`bl_idname = "export_mesh.3mf"`

to

`bl_idname = "export_mesh.three_mf"`

in `%AppData%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\io_mesh_3mf\export_3mf.py`

and also doing the same thing to `%AppData%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\io_mesh_3mf\import_3mf.py` only this time change

`bl_idname = "import_mesh.3mf"`

to

`bl_idname = "import_mesh.three_mf"`

You can then use 3mf import operator in your scripts
`bpy.ops.import_mesh.three_mf(filepath="c:\\some_file.3mf")`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I confirmed that works!